# Decrementing ranges in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am very new to Haskell. Could someone please explain why defining a list like this returns an null list

```
ghci>  let myList = [10..1]
ghci>  myList
[]
```

However this works correctly.

```
ghci>  let myList = [10, 9..1]
ghci>  myList
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Basically, because `[10..1]` is translated to `enumFromTo 10 1` which itself has the semantics to create a list by taking all elements less-than `1` which result from counting upward (with step-size `+1`) from (including) `10`.

Whereas `[10, 9..1]` is translated to `enumFromToThen 10 9 1` which explicitly states the counting step-size as `9-10`, i.e. `-1` (which is hard-coded to `+1` for `enumFromTo`)

A more accurate specification can be found in the Haskell Report (6.3.4  The Enum Class):

```
enumFrom       :: a -> [a]            -- [n..]
enumFromThen   :: a -> a -> [a]       -- [n,n'..]
enumFromTo     :: a -> a -> [a]       -- [n..m]
enumFromThenTo :: a -> a -> a -> [a]  -- [n,n'..m]
```

> For the types `Int` and `Integer`, the enumeration functions have the following meaning:
>
> - The sequence `enumFrom e1` is the list `[e1,e1+1,e1+2,...]`.
> - The sequence `enumFromThen e1 e2` is the list `[e1,e1+i,e1+2i,...]`, where the increment, i, is e2-e1. The increment may be zero or negative. If the increment is zero, all the list elements are the same.
> - The sequence `enumFromTo e1 e3` is the list `[e1,e1+1,e1+2,...e3]`. The list is empty if `e1 > e3`.
> - The sequence `enumFromThenTo e1 e2 e3` is the list `[e1,e1+i,e1+2i,...e3]`, where the increment, `i`, is `e2-e1`. If the increment is positive or zero, the list terminates when the next element would be greater than `e3`; the list is empty if `e1 > e3`. If the increment is negative, the list terminates when the next element would be less than `e3`; the list is empty if `e1 < e3`.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. At first glance I thought this was pretty silly notation but I can see now that it makes it possible to define the size of the steps in the range. Very cool! Very excited about Haskell now :)

Answer (score 15):

Arithmetic sequence notation is just syntactic sugar for functions from the [`Enum`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Enum) class.

```
[a..]     = enumFrom a
[a..b]    = enumFromTo a b
[a, b..]  = enumFromThen a b
[a, b..c] = enumFromThenTo a b c
```

As for why they weren't defined to automatically reverse, I can only speculate but here are some possible reasons:

- If `a` and `b` are defined elsewhere, it would be harder to tell at a glance in which direction `[a..b]` would go.
- It has nicer mathematical properties to reason about. You don't have to add special cases for when the sequence would be reversed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate a list from `a` to `b` regardless of whether `a < b`, you can use the following:

`[a, a + (signum $ b - a)..b]`

Comment: Note that this produces an infinite list if `a = b`.

Comment: `[a, a + (1 / (1 / signum $ b - a)))..b]` fails if a = b

Answer (score 2):

For newbies.

To make a list with all the numbers from 20 to 1, you can't just do

```hs
[20..1]
```

you have to specify as such:

```hs
[20,19..1]
```