# Haskell - what is wrong with this function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

i am trying to compute the harmonic series with the function below. But there's a type error and not quite sure what it mean? another question, why [5..1] would gives an empty list?

> sumHR = foldr (+) 0 (\x -> map (1/) [1..x])

error message:

```
*** Expression     : foldr (+) 0 (\x -> map (1 /) (enumFromTo x 1))
*** Term           : \x -> map (1 /) (enumFromTo x 1)    
*** Type           : b -> [b]    
*** Does not match : [a]
```

Comment: For your other question, see: [Decrementing ranges in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806455/decrementing-ranges-in-haskell)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is telling you that your code is not well-typed and thus doesn't make sense.

Your function:

```
sumHR = foldr (+) 0 (\x -> map (1/) [1..x])
```

Consider:

```
Prelude> :t foldr
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

So for this to be true, `(+)` is the first argument and the types must unify (`a -> b -> b` and `Num a => a -> a -> a` unify to `Num a => a -> a -> a`).

The second argument is given type variable `b`, which we already know must be `Num a => a`.  This is fine, you have provided `0` as the second argument.

The third argument must agree with the type `Num a => [a]`. However, you have provided a second argument that is a function:

```
Prelude> :t (\x -> map (1/) [1..x])
(\x -> map (1/) [1..x]) :: (Enum b, Fractional b) => b -> [b]
```

Unless you can show the compiler how a type of `(Enum b, Fractional b) => b -> [b]` can be made the same as `Num a => [a]` then you are stuck.

You might have ment a function such as:

```
sumHR x = foldr (+) 0 (map (1/) [1..x])
```

Answer (score 4):

Were you trying to write it point-free? If so, you need to use the composition operator `.` to compose `foldr (+) 0` with `(\x -> map (1/) [1..x])`.

```
sumHR = foldr (+) 0 . (\x -> map (1/) [1..x])
```

or, point-fully:

```
sumHR x = foldr (+) 0 (map (1/) [1..x])
```

(By the way, for efficiency you'll want to use `foldl'` instead of `foldr`)

Comment: instead of `fold' (+) 0` why not `sum`?

Comment: i like your answer as well for raising the dot operator!

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers have explained how to fix the function with the signature you apparently want; however this isn't really a good way to compute a *sequence* since for each element you request it will have to start from the beginning. A far more efficient, an in Haskell actually easier, approach is to calculate one lazy list that represents the entire sequence. So, you start with

```
map (1/) [1..]
```

(or, perhaps more readable, `[ 1/i | i<-[1..] ]`), then perform "each element of the result is the sum of all preceding elements in the given list". This is called a *scan*. Since that is always strict in one entire side of the list (rather than just two elements, like a fold) it needs to be done from the left. You can write

```
sumHR' :: Fractional x => [x]
sumHR' = scanl (+) 0 [ 1/i | i<-[1..] ]
```

or, equivalently since the infinite list is never empty,

```
sumHR' = scanl1 (+) [ 1/i | i<-[1..] ]
```