# Keep track of list index with anonymous function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am pretty new to Haskell. so this might be a bit silly.

What I want is to do something like:

```
map (\x -> x + **position in list**) [0, 0, 0] => [1, 2, 3]
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to get indexes is to zip your list with `[0..]` (or `[1..]` if you want 1-based indexes), for example:

```
> zipWith (\i x -> x + i) [1..] [0, 0, 0]
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: It works well, thank you! Do you know if there is any way to use it with positions in reverse? (the result would be [3, 2, 1] instead) I have tried by using 'length list' but it seems that it is not correct.

Comment: @cgf: [Is this the problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806455/decrementing-ranges-in-haskell)

Answer (score 7):

For the moment, let's assume you want to pair each element up with its position in the list. the easy way to do that is:

```
λ> zip [0..] [0, 0, 0]
[(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)]
```

If all you really want is the indices, then all you need is the first `n` elements of `[0..]`, where `n` is the length of the input list. So...

```
λ> let xs = [0,0,0]
λ> [0..length xs - 1]
[0,1,2]
```

Or, equivalently,

```
λ> take (length xs) [0..]
[0,1,2]
```

Comment: A lazier method, which also works for infinite lists, is to use `zipWith const [0..]`.

Comment: Good answer, but @hammar was slightly faster. Thank you!