# enumFromTo that goes in reverse

Tags: haskell

I want to generate a sequence from 10 to 1 descending.

The simplest way using standard library functions is

```
reverse [1..10]
```

However, this is implemented in an inefficient way - it's generating the list and then reversing it. However,

```
[10..1]
```

generates the empty list.

I know that [1..10] is just syntactic sugar for

```
enumFromTo 1 10
```

Is there a standard library "enum*" function which enumerates from a higher element down to the lower one?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no better way of doing this than the `10, 9..1` trick given below. It's a wart of the language design. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806455/decrementing-ranges-in-haskell, which arrived at the same answer.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I have found so far is:

```
[10,9..1]
```

which calls the enumFromThenTo function:

```
enumFromThenTo 10 9 1
 -> [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
[10,9..1]
 -> [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

But is there a wrapper in the standard prelude that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also write your own function:

```
reverseEnum :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
reverseEnum a b
    | a == b = [a]
    | a >= b = a : reverseEnum (a-1) b
    | a <= b = []
```

Here is an example of use:

```
reverseEnum 10 1
-> [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```